# Which field of mathematics should be used to formalize the analysis of a dataset's "geometric" structure

Tags: mathematical-statistics, generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, linear-model, experiment-design

I want to know if mathematical formalism can be applied to understand the "geometric" structure of an experiment's data set, and esp. to the relationships between its categorical predictors.

---

First, defining terms…

Crossed vs. Nesting vs. Nested Categorical Predictors

- Each level of a crossed predictor has a measurement in every level of another predictor.
- Each level of a nesting predictor has a measurement in at least two unique levels of another predictor.
- Each level of a nested predictor has a measurement in only one level of another predictor.

In the pictures shown here, predictors A and B are crossed with each other, predictor C is nesting relative to D, and predictor D is nested within C.

[image]

Note that the levels of a nested predictor MUST be coded with unique identification numbers, otherwise the computer has no way to know that they are nested.

---

Second, some examples…

The most basic "complex" designs I can show here have three categorical predictors. Since this post can't be pages long, I will use a shorthand graphical notation, with the predictors connected by arrows, to describe the Crossed/Nesting/Nested pairwise relationships. A two-directional arrow indicates crossed predictors, and a one-directional dashed arrow points to a nested predictor.

I see four possible combinations of three categorical predictors…

[image]

---

Here are some questions that can be asked (with my thoughts):

- Can this kind of "geometric" predictor information, e.g. data set structure, be used to procedurally specify design matrices for a given experiment? (Yes)
- Are there any mathematical rules, e.g. transitivity of nested predictors, that can be proven? (I don't know)
- Are the pairwise relationships alone enough to specify the design matrices, or is higher dimensional analysis required? Could the answer to this be proven somehow? (Pairwise only analysis is insufficient in some cases, but I don't know why)

Comment: *“Can mathematics be used to formalize the analysis of a dataset's "geometric" structure?”* Obviously yes, but what is the point? The point of the question, what is the problem, is not very clear to me.

Comment: *“Are there any mathematical rules, e.g. transitivity of nested predictors, that can be proven?”* One such rule could be that if B is nested in A and C is nested in B, then also C is nested in A (like the bottom right graph). Corrolary: nesting forms chains that can not be a loop. Your ancestors can not be your kids. If C is nested inside B and also B inside A then C is nested inside A, and the other way around A inside C or A crossed with C is not possible.

Comment: Love the question, but I have to agree with it staying closed. It's a bit too vague, which is as much as to say that it could be at the research level.

Comment: Understood, I will think of a more focused question, and post that one. Thanks!